# Getting MsBuild buildin parameter in custom build task

Tags: msbuild

I have created a custom build template (for TFS 2013) and jacked in the task after the build and now want to make some actions needed.

On parameter that I need to get hold of in the task i the binaryfolder which I feel that MsBuild aldready know but how can I pass this into the task?

Comment: Try running with Diagnostic Logging, you can see all the MSBuild Variables.

Comment: How do I turn on diagnostic logging?

Comment: Open the Queue a New build dialog, goto the Parameters tab, you can set the Verbosity there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are some more searching the net I found that the enum WellKnownEnvironmentVariables points to the variables that I needed just had to create a custom task in the build template of type GetEnvironmentVariable assinging the result to a variable and then passing this variable to a second task that needed the path.